# How to adjust the direction of appearance of GONE views for the MotionLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-transitions, android-motionlayout

See source https://github.com/suchoX/DraggableView

Version `androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-rc1`

Views with attr `gone`(for ex. button `next_image_view` ) are going from the bottom. It is correct. See screen shot

[image]

But if update to Version `androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0`:

The view is going from top-left

[image]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic problem is ConstraintLayout gone ends up at 0,0 size 0,0.

There are two possible solutions.

1. have a 3rd ConstraintSet. So go from normal to invisible then go to Gone.
2. Create KeyFrames of type KeyPosition at framePosition=99 percentX=0, percentY=0

The first fades in the transition to invisible then transitions to Gone.  You can AutoTransition to the second gone.

The Second says 0 movement till you hit the last 1% by which time the they are invisible.